# PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning during manim installing inubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, manim

[image]

when I tried to install manim in ubuntu18.04,I encoutered bug about "PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning".I tried to fix it ,but failed.Hope someone good could help me out,pls.
tags:python3.7 ubuntu18.04 manim

```
Installed /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/manimgl-1.5.0-py3.7.egg
Processing dependencies for manimgl==1.5.0
Searching for manimpango<0.4.0,>=0.2.0
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/manimpango/
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:125: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning:  is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning,
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/04/00af048a5d3a645a053e39db4b3e61da3a8b1b95b6f0d718684028207575/ManimPango-0.3.1.tar.gz#sha256=a3a7e5a417507e9ccf307f6da40291a9fc2757a3c9a04de33dd18e92f63fcc25
Best match: ManimPango 0.3.1
Processing ManimPango-0.3.1.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-ojd30ypi/ManimPango-0.3.1/setup.cfg
Running ManimPango-0.3.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-ojd30ypi/ManimPango-0.3.1/egg-dist-tmp-g764jlvh
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: /tmp/easy_install-ojd30ypi/ManimPango-0.3.1/manimpango/cmanimpango.c: 没有那个文件或目录
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Perhaps you have a missing library? Have you tried to either update your python or update your system?

Comment: I have installed manimpango by `sudo python3.7 -m pip install manimpango`,and the error doesn`t disappear.

Comment: Update python or system? How to ? Is that will destroy my envioment?

Comment: Update `pip` to a recent version (`python -m pip install -U pip`). ManimPango needs Cython while compiling and a recent version of Pip which understands PEP 517 will install Cython when building.

Comment: A normal update would just be something like `yum update`, but @naveen521kk has a good suggestion, too. Updating pip could be the issue. I feel that you're missing a core library so updating either python, pip, or the system should help. Updating should not destroy your env unless you've coded for no growth.

Comment: All right. after many times of attempt, I finally choose to cancel this plan and turn to another way.